# Manage Azure Subscriptions (Customer tenant)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-subscription

As part of a managed service, we register an application in our customers tenant that uses the Graph API.

How can we manage the necessary subscription in such a way that the customer has as little contact with it as possible (we pay the usage because its part of the Service).

Our ideas/variants:
A) Register the subscription in our tenant and release it for the customer to use (is this possible?) If so, what authorizations can we set (least Privilege principle)?

B) creating the subscription in the customer tenant, restrict authorizations so that only our app can use it. Problem: billing should be handled by us; we want to avoid storing credit card information in the customer tenant.

C) Provision as credits (?)

We have already researched and tried a few things, but cannot find a suitable solution.

What (possibly other) concepts are there for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you need subscription for? You can approve the application in customer tenant without having a need of creating subscription.
Depending on what exactly you want to achieve the answer will be different.

Comment: @AliaksandraNeviarouskaya as mentioned, the App uses the Graph-API (Teams Export). So the Payment is basicly for the API usage and not for the application itself

Comment: But you don't need subscription to call the API, you need subscription to create resources in, so my question is still open

Comment: @AliaksandraNeviarouskaya Not sure if i got it right. We create a Ressource group where we combine the appId and subscription together. The rg uses „Microsoft.GraphServices“.

Comment: You can use an app reg from anywhere. It’s the credential to access the graph api. Unless you’re deploying cloud resources to your customer tenant you don’t need a subscription, only the app reg is and a secret

Comment: @Josh can you describe this in more detail please? What we do is, creating a resource group and a subscription (as pay-as-you-go with credit card) via GUI and the following statement with azure cli:

`az resource create --resource-group myRG --name myGraphAppBilling --resource-type Microsoft.GraphServices/accounts --properties  "{`"appId`": `"THE APP ID HERE`"}" --location Global --subscription SUBSCRIPTION ID HERE`

What do you exactly suggest? We also tried adding a foreign appId, but than the message "app id not in this tenant" appears.

Comment: you can create the subscription in your tenant and release it for the customer to use. This is possible, and you can set the appropriate authorizations based on the least privilege principle. Another option is to provision credits for the customer to use, but this may not be suitable for all scenarios.

Comment: References:

-   [Call Microsoft Graph from a Cloud Solution Provider application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-cloudsolutionprovider#token-acquisition-flows)
-   [Subscription considerations and recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/landing-zone/design-area/resource-org-subscriptions#subscription-considerations-and-recommendations)

Comment: This is a bit of a strange question to because as someone providing services to a customer you want as much contact as possible and become very close (customer intimacy). But for MSPs who need to manage Azure subscriptions there is Azure Lighthouse. I have never seen a customer who didn't appreciated that extra call to discuss something how they want something

Answer (score 0):

Managing a subscription has a couple of things that an ISP can do.

For MSPs who need to manage Azure subscriptions there is Azure Lighthouse.

---

Besides that I think it's a good to leverage infrastructure as code as much possible and deploy bicep templates using Azure DevOps to a customer tenant. You can design a standard solution with templates you can deploy at every customer (with some minimal changes) per customer. For example a subscription with a key vault and peering to a central network hub, and some policies and access control to enforce some guardrails.

---

Besides that there is maybe a need for monitoring the subscription. You deploy a log analytics workspace and monitor a basis set of events of alerts. For example the activity log of each subscription, to get notified when changes happen.

---

Then the customer might have a need for security monitoring you could leverage Sentinel to setup some security monitoring and Defender for Cloud to check the security posture.

---

Answer (score 0):

User Managed Service Registration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.managedservices/2020-02-01-preview/registrationdefinitions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep